# different html, body background based on URL or URL string prefix

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, css

Basically I have a **custom wordpress website.**

I have a custom **wp-login.php** login screen.

But, the login screen leads to a **sign-up page** *(enabled)*.

The sign-up page basically loads 2 different fields dynamically within the same **form** `id` that allows users to sign-up. Everything is the same everywhere else. (Replaces first frame 'login' page)

The **problem**.. is, the login page has my custom background image on `html, body { background:`

I would like the user to see a unique `background:` **image** when they hit that form. *(the 2nd form, SIGN-UP)*

Below is the URL that is generated once the user hits signup:

```
/wp-login.php?action=register
```

Is there a way I can simply replace the `html, body { background:` with a ***NEW*** one when the user reaches that URL?

Comment: You could just add a class to your body named after the action parameter in your header.php and predefine those classes with the background you want to use there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way to do it.

You can put in your *wp-login.php* a new css rule with [!important](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/), like this:

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='register'){
         echo '<style>html, body { background: url("link_of_another_image.png") !important }</style>';
    }

?>
```

Maybe, it can help you

Answer (score 1):

I would do (not best way (it's probably the worst one :D) but fast to implement and works) this:

Open index.php and add code below to it:

```
<?php
if (stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?action=register'))
ob_start(function($html) {
  $before = array('<body','<html');
  $style = ' style="background: ..."';
  $after = array('<body'.$style,'<html'.$style);
  $html = str_replace($before,$after,$html);
  return $html;
});
```

Comment: Where would you suggest inserting this? I put this in the index.php right after get_header(); ?> and didn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the action=register parameter using javascript on page load and add a class to your body element.
Then, you could override the styles as something like

```
body.registration { background: ...}
```

Comment: Isn't `$_GET['action']` accessible in the header.php where your `body` is defined in wordpress? then you just could do it serverside like in my comment to the question.

Comment: In the theme's header.php? I didn't see that in admin-header.php or theme's header.php